# load external qml file on android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

I am developing an app for android with QT/QML. To switch between screens I use this pageloader:

```
Rectangle {
id: mainApp
visible: true
width: 768
height: 1030


    signal handlerLoader(string name, int index)
    Loader {
        id:pageLoader
        source:"mainMenu.qml"
    }
    Connections {
        target:pageLoader.item
        onHandlerLoader:{pageLoader.source=name;
            if(index===2)
                window.source="NewWindow.qml";
        }
    }}
```

In a menu I have a button somewhere where another screen is loaded:

```
Button {
          id: continueButton
          width: 600
          height: 150

          text: "Continue with last template"
          onClicked: handlerLoader("Template_water.qml",0)
      }
```

This works, because Template_water.qml is in the qml.qrc file. But now I want to load in another file which is on the external storage on my android device: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Template_water.qml". But it is not described in the qml.qrc file so it doesn't load. How can I solve this? (I want it to be able to add a qml file after deployment on the device.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to provide scheme for your url like:
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Template_water.qml